# How can I change the time keeper's input font size in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change this input's size

[image]

here .html component

```
    <div class="time-picker" dir="ltr">
                                                    <ngx-timepicker-field [defaultTime]="'00:00'" [format]="24" [clockTheme]="theme"></ngx-timepicker-field>
                                                </div>
```

here .ts component

```
import { NgxMaterialTimepickerTheme } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';

theme: NgxMaterialTimepickerTheme = {
        container: {
          bodyBackgroundColor: '#25bcbd',
          buttonColor: '#fff',
        },
        dial: {
            dialBackgroundColor: '#4fcbcc',
        },
        clockFace: {
          clockFaceBackgroundColor: '#e6e7e8',
          clockHandColor: '#25bcbd',
          clockFaceTimeInactiveColor: '#4f5757',
        },
    };
```

I searched and didn't find the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no configuration in the documentation, instead go for custom CSS solution like so.

```
.custom-timepicker-css {
  .timepicker-dial__container {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .timepicker-dial__control {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
  }
  .timepicker-dial__time {
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
}
```

html

```
<ngx-mat-timepicker
  timepickerClass="custom-timepicker-css"
  #timepicker
  [enableKeyboardInput]="true"
  [max]="maxTime"
  [min]="minTime"
></ngx-mat-timepicker>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-timepicker-9dvav4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fstyles.scss)